# stopPropagation on ipad/iphone in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing hover menu that functions well across all browsers and devices i have tested. Inside this menu, i have added a input box for login and password and now when touching the password field on the ipad/iphone using Safari, it triggers the menu to close. This behavior happens in IE(desktop) also.

To fix this in IE, I used this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".subnav-container select").mouseleave(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
</script>
```

After adding this fix, the issue still remains in Safari on ipad/iphone. However, it works properly in Chrome on ipad/iphone.

I have tried this fix for mobile Safari, but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function ( e )  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
}, false);
</script>
```

I tried touchenter , touchleave , touchstart but have no experience with how to apply a fix for touchscreen device issues.

My basic html is as follows:

```
    <div data-async-loaded="loaded" data-gadget="menu.gadget.MyMenuNav" data-load="preloaded">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="tier0">       
      <div class="shop facet nav-section" data-subnav="tab1" data-nav-tracking="tab1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="font-family--platform button-font-size--small facet-label">
            LOGIN
            <span class="arrow-down text--medium-light-grey">
            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tier1">   
       <div data-subnav="tab1" class="subnav tracking is-hidden" data-nav-tracking="tab1">
        <div class="subnav-container">
          <div class="subnav-section">
            <div class="subnav-item l-w6 visual-format">
              <form name="login" action="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/login" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="LEAGUE_ID" value="24779"  /> 
              <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule report" id="welcome"><caption><span>Welcome</span></caption><tbody><tr><th colspan="2">Guest</th></tr>
              <tr class="oddtablerow"><td class="inputlabel">Login As:</td>
              <td><select size="1" name="FRANCHISE_ID">
              <option value="0000">Commissioner</option>
              <option value="0001">UR4BIDN</option>
              <option value="0002">NIKE TEAM B</option>
              <option value="0003">NIKE TEAM C</option>
              <option value="0004">Franchise 4</option>
              <option value="0005">Franchise 5</option>
              <option value="0006">Franchise 6</option>
              <option value="0007">Franchise 7</option>
              <option value="0008">Franchise 8</option>
              <option value="0009">Franchise 9</option>
              <option value="0010">Franchise 10</option>
              <option value="0011">TRADEA</option>
              <option value="0012">TRADEB</option>
              </select></td></tr>
              <tr class="eventablerow"><td class="inputlabel">Password:</td><td><input name="PASSWORD" type="password" size="10"  /> </td></tr>
              <tr class="oddtablerow"><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"  /> </td></tr>
              </tbody></table></form>
            </div>                
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>          
      </div>     
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a link to your working code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You have not included all of the code needed for others to be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('touchend', function ( e )  {
    e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem for iPhones!
You need to set "Propagation" directly on element in DOM.
The rest of JS can be written in the usual way.
Example:

```
<body>
   <a href="https://google.com"> Parent that should remain unaffected <br><br>
      
      <p onclick="function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();};"> 
         Clicking here will not activate the "A" tag 
      </p>
   
   </a>
</body>

<script>
   $('div').click(function(){
      window.location = "https://samborsky.pro";
   });
</script>
```